Gitlab-runner on gitlab server - modifying git-repo url
I am currently trying to setup an instance runner for our gitlab and it should run on the same machine for now.
I registered the runner to access the gitlab instance via localhost and it is online.
When starting a pipeline, the runner tries to connect to the the gitlab repo as stated in the gitlab config.rb.
The gitlab-runner fails with a timeout and therefore I would like to force it to use localhost instead of the IP that is mentioned in the gitlab config.
Is there a way to configure the gitlab-runner accordingly?
Thanks everyone in advance!
